# SharePoint API to get Crawling information

Tags: sharepoint, moss

I'm trying to create a custom report that shows Current Crawling Time/Duration with Status on either Full or Incremental Crawl.

Does anyone know what the API that I can use to get such the information?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is the Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Administration.CrawlHistory class.

The SDK even has an article on this:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc789570.aspx

Comment: Thanks. It looks interesting - will take a closer look.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure of the name but here is a good series of articles on the search API and may point you in the correct direction if someone cannot provide the full name.

http://www.helloitsliam.com/archive/2009/05/01/moss2007-–-using-the-search-api-part-1.aspx

Comment: thanks for your response. What we're looking for is the API that we can use to build a report related to current crawling duration and status, pretty much the same information as what we can see on the Central Admin.